# Resolving SSL Protocol Error on data connection but not on wifi

Tags: browser, https

When I try to access secure web sites via https (ssl), I get an error.

Chrome error message:

```
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) SSL_Protocol Error
```

Firefox error message:

```
ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
```

The website load correctly on Wifi, but this error shows up when trying to load pages over a cellular data connection.

I am running Cyanogenmod 10 (Android 4.1.2) from Bell (Canada), though the problem also happens on stock Android (according to other forums on other carriers).

I tried following one person's suggestion to modify the TLD settings in the `about:config` page for Firefox, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you considered posting to CyanogenMod forums about this?

Comment: Hmm, maybe your carrier is messing around with SSL connections.

Comment: Turns out I had to remove the proxy settings from the data network.